# How to use variables in mailgun API?

Tags: php, api, mailgun

How I can use variables in mailgun?

In the test email (test@example.com) I added the following variable

```
{"age": 20}
```

but it does not go as is used when creating the mail.

Here goes the code when the mail is sent.

```
$mailformat = "CODE HTML :D";
$result = $mgClient->sendMessage($domain, array(
    'from'    => 'Example <example@example.com>',
    'to'      => 'test@example.com',
    'subject' => '%recipient_fname%, testing mail',
    'html'    => $mailformat
));
```

Comment: It is not obvious what you are asking.  Please provide the code where you have used it.  Also what you are getting / what is it doing.  And what are you expecting it to do ?

Comment: How you already check if [some of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmailgun%5D+variables) deals with your issue?

Comment: I'm a little confused, you have the variable but you don't do anything with it. If you want to pass it to the body of the mail, you can do it as concatenation.

Answer (score 5):

You should add the user variables this way:

```
v:age=20
```

If you're using Python, in the data element you must add

```
data={
   'from' : 'Name <email@email>',
   'to'   : email_list,
    ...
   'v:age' : '20'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://documentation.mailgun.com/api-sending.html#sending):

v: prefix followed by an arbitrary name allows to attach a custom JSON data to the message. See [Attaching Data to Messages](https://documentation.mailgun.com/user_manual.html#manual-customdata) for more information.

Comment: But this refers to when I add the variables in the API, not when the call attempt from the "site" (so to speak)